# SQL Queries should do the same thing but don't

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The two SQL queries below should give me exactly the same result, but for some reason the first query which uses a join instead of a sub query gives me far more results. The only difference is the last line in both samples. Can anyone tell me why?

```
SELECT *
FROM TravelReport TR
  JOIN School SC ON SC.SchoolId = TR.SchoolId 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [User] U ON U.UserId = TR.UserId
                          AND U.UserTypeId = 3 
                          AND U.UserStatusId = 1 
  JOIN ProjectSchools PS ON PS.SchoolId = SC.SchoolId
WHERE PS.Active = 1
  AND PS.ProjectId = 2
```

=====

```
SELECT *
FROM TravelReport TR
  JOIN School SC ON SC.SchoolId = TR.SchoolId 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [User] U ON U.UserId = TR.UserId
                          AND U.UserTypeId = 3 
                          AND U.UserStatusId = 1 
WHERE SC.SchoolId in (SELECT DISTINCT PS.SchoolId FROM ProjectSchools PS
                      WHERE PS.Active = 1 AND PS.ProjectId = 2)
```

Comment: The only way those 2 queries would give the same results is if `SchoolId` is unique in the `ProjectSchools` table, and obviously, that's not true in your scenario

Comment: Just a side remark: Don't use DISTINCT on IN clauses. Leave it to the DBMS to decide how to look up values in the list. It may or may not decide to use distinct on the list first.

Answer (score 0):

Can eliminate the left as it should not effect any count.
Are you sure you are not just getting more of the same result?

```
SELECT *
  FROM TravelReport TR      
  JOIN School SC 
        ON SC.SchoolId = TR.SchoolId  
  JOIN ProjectSchools PS 
        ON PS.SchoolId = SC.SchoolId 
 WHERE PS.Active    = 1
   AND PS.ProjectId = 2
=====

SELECT *
  FROM TravelReport TR
  JOIN School SC 
        ON SC.SchoolId = TR.SchoolId  
 WHERE SC.SchoolId in ( SELECT DISTINCT PS.SchoolId 
                          FROM ProjectSchools PS
                         WHERE PS.Active    = 1 
                           AND PS.ProjectId = 2 )
```

Consider this

```
SchoolID  Active  ProjectID 
10        1       2
10        1       2 
10        1       1
11        2       2
12        1       2
13        1       2
13        2       2
```

The first will return two rows for schoolID 10 and the second will not

Maybe a school can have multiple active projects so you cannot make SchoolID unique
At lease put a unique constraint on SchoolID, Active, ProjedtID

Or just put a distinct in the select *
select distinct *

If something else is going on please post actual data to reproduce the problem